# Adding stippling to image/contour plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

have some data that I would like to add "stippling" to show where it is "important", as they do in the IPCC plots

[image: http://www.ipcc.ch/graphics/ar4-wg1/jpg/fig-10-18.jpg]

At the moment I am really struggling with trying to do this in R.

If I make up some test data and plot it:

```
data <- array(runif(12*6), dim=c(12,6) )
over <- ifelse(data > 0.5, 1, 0 )
image(1:12, 1:6, data)
```

What I would like to finally do is over-plot some points based on the array "over" on top of the current image.

Any suggestions!??

Comment: ?points is the usual way

Comment: Hi mdsumner, if I try adding points as in:
>> points(over)
I end up with one point in the bottom left of the plot. Are there extra arguments to pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it using the coordinate positioning mechanism of `?image` [1].

```
data(volcano)
m <- volcano
dimx <- nrow(m)
dimy <- ncol(m)

d1 <- list(x = seq(0, 1, length = dimx), y = seq(0, 1, length = dimy), z = m)
```

With your 'image' constructed that way you keep the structure with the object, and its 
coordinates intact. You can collect multiple matrices into a 3D array or as multiple 
elements, but you need to augment `image()` in order to handle that, so I keep them 
separate here.

Make a copy of the data to specify an interesting area.

```
d2 <- d1
d2$z <- d2$z > 155
```

Use the coordinates to specify which cells are interesting. This is expensive if you have a very big raster, but it's super easy to do.

```
pts <- expand.grid(x = d2$x, y = d2$y)
pts$over <- as.vector(d2$z)
```

Set up the plot.

```
op <- par(mfcol = c(2, 1))
image(d1)

image(d1)
points(pts$x[pts$over], pts$y[pts$over], cex = 0.7)

par(op)
```

Don't forget to modify the plotting of points to get different effects, in particular a very dense grid with lots of points will take ages to draw all those little circles. `pch = "."` is a good choice.

Now, do you have some real data to plot on that nice projection? See examples here for some of the options: http://spatial-analyst.net/wiki/index.php?title=Global_datasets

[1] R has classes for more sophisticated handling of raster data, see package sp and raster 
for two different approaches.

Comment: thanks for this example, which works really easily! I also had a look at the sp package, which seems very powerful!

Answer (score 10):

This should help - I had do do a similar thing before and wrote a function that I posted [here](http://menugget.blogspot.de/2012/04/create-polygons-from-matrix.html).

```
#required function from www.menugget.blogspot.com
matrix.poly <- function(x, y, z=mat, n=NULL){
 if(missing(z)) stop("Must define matrix 'z'")
 if(missing(n)) stop("Must define at least 1 grid location 'n'")
 if(missing(x)) x <- seq(0,1,,dim(z)[1])
 if(missing(y)) y <- seq(0,1,,dim(z)[2])
 poly <- vector(mode="list", length(n))
 for(i in seq(length(n))){
  ROW <- ((n[i]-1) %% dim(z)[1]) +1
  COL <- ((n[i]-1) %/% dim(z)[1]) +1
 
  dist.left <- (x[ROW]-x[ROW-1])/2
  dist.right <- (x[ROW+1]-x[ROW])/2
  if(ROW==1) dist.left <- dist.right
  if(ROW==dim(z)[1]) dist.right <- dist.left
 
  dist.down <- (y[COL]-y[COL-1])/2
  dist.up <- (y[COL+1]-y[COL])/2
  if(COL==1) dist.down <- dist.up
  if(COL==dim(z)[2]) dist.up <- dist.down
 
  xs <- c(x[ROW]-dist.left, x[ROW]-dist.left, x[ROW]+dist.right, x[ROW]+dist.right)
  ys <- c(y[COL]-dist.down, y[COL]+dist.up, y[COL]+dist.up, y[COL]-dist.down)
  poly[[i]] <- data.frame(x=xs, y=ys)
 }
 return(poly)
}

#make vector of grids for hatching
incl <- which(over==1)

#make polygons for each grid for hatching
polys <- matrix.poly(1:12, 1:6, z=over, n=incl)

    #plot
png("hatched_image.png")
image(1:12, 1:6, data)
for(i in seq(polys)){
    polygon(polys[[i]], density=10, angle=45, border=NA)
    polygon(polys[[i]], density=10, angle=-45, border=NA)
}
box()
dev.off()
```

[image]

Or, and alternative with "stipples":

```
png("hatched_image2.png")
image(1:12, 1:6, data)
for(i in seq(polys)){
    xran <- range(polys[[i]]$x)
    yran <- range(polys[[i]]$y)
    xs <- seq(xran[1], xran[2],,5)
    ys <- seq(yran[1], yran[2],,5)
    grd <- expand.grid(xs,ys)
    points(grd, pch=19, cex=0.5)
}
box()
dev.off()
```

[image]

#### Update:

In (very late) response to Paul Hiemstra's comment, here are two more examples with a matrix of higher resolution. The hatching maintains a nice regular pattern, but it is not nice to look at when broken up. The stippled example is much nicer:

```
n <- 100
x <- 1:n
y <- 1:n
M <- list(x=x, y=y, z=outer(x, y, FUN = function(x,y){x^2 * y * rlnorm(n^2,0,0.2)}))
image(M)
range(M$z)
incl <- which(M$z>5e5)

polys <- matrix.poly(M$x, M$y, z=M$z, n=incl)

png("hatched_image.png", height=5, width=5, units="in", res=400)
op <- par(mar=c(3,3,1,1))
image(M)
for(i in seq(polys)){
  polygon(polys[[i]], density=10, angle=45, border=NA, lwd=0.5)
  polygon(polys[[i]], density=10, angle=-45, border=NA, lwd=0.5)
}
box()
par(op)
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
png("stippled_image.png", height=5, width=5, units="in", res=400)
op <- par(mar=c(3,3,1,1))
image(M)
grd <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
points(grd$x[incl], grd$y[incl], pch=".", cex=1.5)
box()
par(op)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: +1! How do the plot's look when the amount of pixels is much larger, say 10 tens more resolution?

Comment: Hi Marc! That works great for image type plots (including image.plot)! I guess if I use filled.contour then I just need to pass the call to polygon to the plot.axis argument..
Thanks!

Comment: @Paul - not sure that I understand your question completely. You may have to fiddle with the point size to make the stippling easy on the eye. Otherwise, you could use the same matrix.poly function to add some other type of polygon on top (e.g. a semi-transparent layer that also highlights the grids?)

Comment: @Alex - I used image, because it gives one more flexibility with adding lower-level plotting details after the main plot - I'm not sure that filled.contour would allow for that. Without trying to promote my blog too much here, I have also written a function that allows one to add a scale for a corresponding image plot: http://menugget.blogspot.de/2011/08/adding-scale-to-image-plot.html . As you can see, this question is at the heart of things that I have been dealing with recently as well. I'm not experienced with ggplot2, but if you're willing to invest the time, it might be worth it

Comment: @Marcinthebox, that was exactly what I meant, if the amount of pixels becomes large, you might need to tweak with the point size.

Comment: @Marcinthebox, thanks for the reply and the link to your blog (which is very very useful!). I have tried the function with filled.contour and it does indeed work when passed in using the plot.axis argument.

Comment: @Marcinthebox. This is a nice function. I encountered an issue when a matrix defines a mask with only a single cell: `testmat <- matrix(c(0,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,0),nrow=3); matrix.poly(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3), testmat, which(testmat==1))   # Error in if (ROW == 1) dist.left <- dist.right : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. I don't seem to be able to figure out how to avoid the error. Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution in the spirit of @mdsummer's comment using ggplot2. I first draw the grid, and then draw `+`'es at the locations where a certain value has been exceeded. Note that `ggplot2` works with `data.frame`'s, not with multi-dimensional arrays or matrices. You can use `melt` from the `reshape` package to convert from an array / marix to a data.frame flat structure.

Here is a concrete example using the example data from the `geom_tile` documentation:

```
pp <- function (n,r=4) { 
 x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n) 
 df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x) 
 df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2) 
 df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6) 
 df 
} 

require(ggplot2)
dat = pp(200)
over = dat[,c("x","y")]
over$value = with(dat, ifelse(z > 0.5, 1, 0))
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = dat) + 
   geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) + 
   scale_fill_gradient2() +
   geom_point(data = subset(over, value == 1), shape = "+", size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the ggplot solution. I think I will try out the solution from Marcinthebox as I tend not to use lattice graphics.. but maybe I should start to!

Answer (score 3):

This is probably coming too late, but I'd like to post my answer as a reference too.

One nice option for spatial data is to use the rasterVis package. Once you have a "base" raster object, and the "mask" object, which you will use to draw the stippling, you can do something like:

```
require(raster)
require(rasterVis)

# Scratch raster objects
data(volcano)
r1 <- raster(volcano)

# Here we are selecting only values from 160 to 180.
# This will be our "mask" layer.
over <- ifelse(volcano >=160 & volcano <=180, 1, NA) 
r2 <- raster(over)

# And this is the key step:
# Converting the "mask" raster to spatial points
r.mask <- rasterToPoints(r2, spatial=TRUE)

# Plot
levelplot(r1, margin=F) +
layer(sp.points(r.mask, pch=20, cex=0.3, alpha=0.8))
```

which resembles the map that the OP was looking for. Parameters of the points such as color, size and type can be fine tuned. ?sp.points provides all the arguments that can be used to do that.