# Raster overlay visualization in rasterVis package: How the Significant raster images are represented as point marks?

Tags: r, visualization, raster, rastervis

I have two raster image: Trend Raster and Significant raster. I want to overly the significant raster to trend raster that i can show siginificant and trend at sametime.

I want to draw a picture,like the below:
[image]

Recently, i find the **rasterVis** package. It's a good tool to visualize the raster. Furthermore, the **leveplot** function seem like meet my demand. I confuse how can i show the significant raster as a dot in **rasterVis** package. Any idea?

My problem:

1. How can i draw a clear map using "+"shape?
2. How can i remove the grey color in background?
3. Is there anyway to use "rasterVis"package and other package to visuliaze this?

But now, i just show it like this. The black dot is significant mark. As you see,this is not a good idea. If
i use "+"shape, it will fill full map.
[image]
Here is my code(It's run so long, maybe is the **fill=value**.I actuall need a quickly draw):

```
P<-raster(file.choose())
P[P>=0.05]<-NA
test_P <- as(P, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
test_P <- as.data.frame(test_P)
Trend111<- raster(file.choose())
test_trend111 <- as(Trend111, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
test_trend111 <- as.data.frame(test_trend111)
colnames(test_trend111) <- c("value", "x", "y")
ggplot() +geom_raster(data = test_trend111,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=value))+
  scale_fill_gradient("Trend2",low = 'yellow', high = 'green',na.value = NA)+
  geom_point(data=test_P,aes(x = x, y = y),shape=".",na.value = NA)#,alpha = 0.05,size=2,stroke=0)
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11737936/1199289

Comment: Thank you @Marc in the box. I looked after the link. I used "ggplot2" package as@Paul Hiemstra to draw the fig. But it  takes hours but i see nothing. The R code still working to draw....My trend and significant Raster file size is 22MB. It's that normal for the working time？Any idea to speed up?